# What happens when sound source is radiating through a hole in a cavity?

Tags: waves, acoustics

What happens to the external sound field , when loudspeaker attached to one wall is radiating inside a box and other  wall has a aperture size of a diaphragm? Do we experience Helmholtz effect?

Answer (score 0):

Helmholtz effect occurs when pressure outside the box (i.e. external pressure change). There will be a whistling at certain frequency. The controlling parameters are aperture size and volume of the box.

When a loudspeaker inside the box radiates, it just radiates with wave bouncing on the walls and some emits out of the aperture. Resonance occurs at certain frequency depending on the size of the box (i.e. wave traveling distance).